# Getting the boundary box of a rotating image in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to make a render engine and I have some difficulty with my calculations. The problem is that I want to get the drawn boundary box of an image to detect if this image is in the canvas limit or not.

But it gets complicated because I have a position, a pivot position (not always centered with the image) and a rotation. I searched and I didn't find any post that speaks of this particular problem althought this is a very usefull feature.

Here is my work so far :
https://jsfiddle.net/feo196nm/

```
function getBoundaryDraw(x, y, pivotX, pivotY, width, height, rotationRadian) {
  // getting the width and height
  var realWidth = Math.abs(Math.cos(rotationRadian)) * width + Math.abs(Math.sin(rotationRadian)) * height;
  var realHeight = Math.abs(Math.cos(rotationRadian)) * height + Math.abs(Math.sin(rotationRadian)) * width;

  // trying to get the position in canvas
  // I dont know what I'm doing **insert mad scientist dog here**
  var dx = pivotX - width / 2;
  var dy = pivotY - height / 2;
  var h = Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
  var da = rotationRadian + Math.asin(dx/h);
  var x = x + pivotX + width / 2 - realWidth / 2 - h * Math.cos(da);
  var y = y + pivotY + height / 2 - realHeight / 2 - h * Math.sin(da);

  // log result to have some debug
  console.log(dx, dy, h, da, x, y);

  // return random numbers
  return {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    width: realWidth,
    height: realHeight
  };
}
```

It's not working ... I used almost all the combinations. Please help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer in code. Compute the x and y rotated scaled axis then use them to compute corner locations, then find the min and max of all corners to get the extent.

It will work for images scaled independently including negative scales and zero scales. The image origin can be inside or outside the image but is not included in the extent.

The demo shows several images rotated, with scale, origin set for bothe axis and their bounding box ( extent ) and the bounding box of all the images.

Hope this helps.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 400;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var image = new Image();
image.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7qq2.png?s=328&g=1";

// get the extent of an Image object with its
// origin at x,y (local origin cx,cy) scaled sx, sy
// and rotated ang.
// returns extent object.
// if you supply an extent will add to it if it is valid
function getImageBounds(img, x, y, cx, cy, sx, sy, ang, extent) {
    var xdx = Math.cos(ang) * sx; // x axis
    var xdy = Math.sin(ang) * sx;

    var ydx = -Math.sin(ang) * sy; // y axis
    var ydy = Math.cos(ang) * sy;

    if (extent === null || extent === undefined) { // create extent if does not exist
        extent = {
            top : Infinity,
            left : Infinity,
            right : -Infinity,
            bottom : -Infinity,
        };
    }
    var r = img.width - cx; // right coord
    var b = img.height - cy; // bottom
    var p = [// the 4 corner points [x,y,x,y...
        -cx * xdx + (-cy * ydx) + x,
        -cx * xdy + (-cy * ydy) + y,
        r * xdx + (-cy * ydx) + x,
        r * xdy + (-cy * ydy) + y,
        r * xdx + b * ydx + x,
        r * xdy + b * ydy + y,
         - cx * xdx + b * ydx + x,
         - cx * xdy + b * ydy + y,
    ];
    extent.left = Math.min(extent.left, p[0], p[2], p[4], p[6]);
    extent.top = Math.min(extent.top, p[1], p[3], p[5], p[7]);
    extent.right = Math.max(extent.right, p[0], p[2], p[4], p[6]);
    extent.bottom = Math.max(extent.bottom, p[1], p[3], p[5], p[7]);
    extent.width = extent.right - extent.left;
    extent.height = extent.bottom - extent.top;
    return extent;
}
function drawImage(img) { // draws image
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, img.x, img.y)

    ctx.rotate(img.ang);
    ctx.scale(img.sx, img.sy);

    ctx.drawImage(image, -img.cx, -img.cy);
}

function createImg() { // image object factory
    return {
        x : 0,
        y : 0,
        cx : 0,
        cy : 0,
        sx : 1,
        sy : 1,
        ang : 0,
    };
}

var imgs = [createImg(), createImg(), createImg(), createImg(), createImg(), createImg(), createImg(), createImg()];
ctx.lineWidth = 2;

// primes 467, 479, 487, 491, 499,859, 863, 877, 881, 883,
function update(time) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#888";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 400);
    if (image.complete) {
        time = time * 0.08;
        for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i += 1) { // move images properties semi random
            var g = imgs[i];
            var t1 = time / (467 + i * 877);
            var t2 = time / (863 + i * 499);
            g.x = Math.cos(t1) * 300 + 400;
            g.y = Math.sin(t2) * 150 + 200;
            t1 *= 5;
            t2 *= 5;
            g.sx = Math.cos(t1) * 0.32 * Math.cos(t2);
            g.sy = Math.sin(t2) * 0.32 * Math.cos(t1);
            t1 *= 5;
            t2 *= 5;
            g.cx = Math.cos(t1) * image.width * 0.5 + image.width * 0.5;
            g.cy = Math.sin(t2) * image.height * 0.5 + image.height * 0.5;
            g.ang += Math.sin(t2/6) * 0.1;
            t1 *= 5;
            t2 *= 5;
        }
        var extentAll = null; // to get extent all
        for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i += 1) { // draw image and get extent and show extent
            var g = imgs[i];
            drawImage(g);
            extentAll = getImageBounds(image, g.x, g.y, g.cx, g.cy, g.sx, g.sy, g.ang, extentAll);
            var extent = getImageBounds(image, g.x, g.y, g.cx, g.cy, g.sx, g.sy, g.ang);
            ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); /// reset the transform
            ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
            ctx.strokeRect(extent.left, extent.top, extent.width, extent.height);
            ctx.fillStyle = "#FA0";
            ctx.fillRect(g.x - 5, g.y - 5, 10, 10);

        }
        ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
        ctx.strokeRect(extentAll.left, extentAll.top, extentAll.width, extentAll.height);

    } else {
        ctx.font = "32px arial";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        ctx.fillText("Loading...", 400, 200);
    }

    // do it all again

    requestAnimationFrame(update);

}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```